# Создать xml из сткового массива

Tags: java, xml

Есть функция, которая отдает мне строковый массив. Причем этот массив больше xml, чем массив и работать с ним не совсем удобно, в плане получения и манипуляции с данными. Подскажите, можно ли создать xml из массива типа `String[][]`(количество вложенных уровней 5, количество начальных элементов 40, то есть String[40][5], в дальнейшем будет наполняться). И удобно ли вообще работать с такими сложно получаемыми данными.
Вывод функции выглядит слудующим образом:

```
anyType{ArrayOfCGetInvoicesRequestsEl=anyType{ID=23; NAME=Audi; DESCRIPTION=anyType{}; DEPTH_LEVEL=1; }; 
ArrayOfCGetInvoicesRequestsEl=anyType{ID=93; NAME=Audi A1; DESCRIPTION=anyType{}; IBLOCK_SECTION_ID=23; DEPTH_LEVEL=2; }; 
ArrayOfCGetInvoicesRequestsEl=anyType{ID=28; NAME=Audi A3; DESCRIPTION=anyType{}; IBLOCK_SECTION_ID=23; DEPTH_LEVEL=2; }; 
ArrayOfCGetInvoicesRequestsEl=anyType{ID=29; NAME=Audi A4; DESCRIPTION=anyType{}; IBLOCK_SECTION_ID=23; DEPTH_LEVEL=2; }; 
ArrayOfCGetInvoicesRequestsEl=anyType{ID=97; NAME=Audi A5; DESCRIPTION=anyType{}; IBLOCK_SECTION_ID=23; DEPTH_LEVEL=2; };
```

Я хочу вытащить из этого массива элементы с DEPTH_LEVEL=1, которые будут связанны с элементами DEPTH_LEVEL=2, и вывести в два спиннера, один зависит от другого.

Comment: На сколько я понимаю глубина массива не большая? UPD количество вложенных уровней потенциального XML )

Comment: `xml` создать можно из чего угодно. Другое дело, что если твоя функция возвращает `String[][]`, то у тебя явные проблемы с архитектурой приложения.

Comment: @Темкатоже в чем заключаются мои проблемы с архитектурой? можно тут подробнее

Comment: Не видя что делает функция сложно говорить о том что лучше, и как лучше. Перевод `String[][]` в `xml` может выглядеть в результате плачевно. Если же 40 начальных элементов имеют по 5 вложенных элементов одинаковой структуры, то проще было бы описать структуру или класс вложенных элементов и создать что-то на подобии `List<Class>` тогда сериализация этого `списка` в `xml` ограничивалась бы парой строчек в `linq`

Comment: Я думал об этом. И сейчас продолжаю думать. А пока продолжу работать с полученным xml, посмотрим к чему это приведет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение, наверно, не совсем оптимальное, но я вымучал. Выложу код, может быть кому пригодится.

```
SoapObject[] temp = new SoapObject[resultsString.getPropertyCount()];
int resultsString.getPropertyCount()=40;
String[][] items2 = new String[resultsString.getPropertyCount()][5];
        for (int i=0;i<resultsString.getPropertyCount();i++) {
            temp[i] = (SoapObject) resultsString.getProperty(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < temp[i].getPropertyCount(); j++) {
                items2[i][j] = String.valueOf(temp[i].getProperty(j));
            }
        }
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory =
                DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder =
                dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.newDocument();
        org.w3c.dom.Element rootElement = doc.createElement("result");
        doc.appendChild(rootElement);
        for ( int i=0; i<resultsString.getPropertyCount();i++)
        {
            org.w3c.dom.Element row = doc.createElement("row" + String.valueOf(i));
            rootElement.appendChild(row);
            for (int j = 0; j < temp[i].getPropertyCount(); j++) {
                temp[i].getPropertyInfo(j,pr);
                org.w3c.dom.Element rowElement = doc.createElement(pr.name); //ID
                rowElement.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(String.valueOf(temp[i].getProperty(j)))); //value
                row.appendChild(rowElement);
            }
        }
```